# Yii2 add glyphicon into dataColumn

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
[
        'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute'=>'bumi_status',
        'value'=>function($model,$url){
            if($model->bumi_status == 'Bumi')
            {
                //return 'Yes';
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>';
            }
            else
            {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
            }
        }
    ],
```

I would like to return a glyhpicon instead of word inside the column  but now it showing the full sentence. Anyway how to make it show the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add: `'format' => 'raw'`:

```
[
    'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'bumi_status',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value'=>function($model,$url){
        if($model->bumi_status == 'Bumi')
        {
            //return 'Yes';
            return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>';
        }
        else
        {
            return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
        }
    }
],
```

As described in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$format-detail):

> In which format should the value of each data model be displayed as
>   (e.g. "raw", "text", "html", ['date', 'php:Y-m-d']). Supported formats
>   are determined by the formatter used by the yii\grid\GridView. Default
>   format is "text" which will format the value as an HTML-encoded plain
>   text when yii\i18n\Formatter is used as the formatter of the GridView.

The default is `text` so Yii format it as HTML-encoded, and it formats the value. If the format is `raw` it just display the value as is.